# Using Qiskit VQE for solving an eigenvalue problem

Tags: qiskit, programming, vqe, linear-algebra

I am a new user of Qiskit and I believe there is a simple answer to my question but I have had a very hard time finding a straightforward answer. I am trying to transform a given $3 \times 3$ (Hermitian) Hamiltonian matrix into a qubit operator and then use the built-in VQE solver for evaluating the minimum eigenvalue for said matrix.

I have been successful in doing something similar using the `qiskit.chemistry.FermionicOperator` built-in class (see example below) but for this example the Hamiltonian is mapped to a Fermionic one-body qubit Hamiltonian which has $2^n$ eigenvalues instead of $n$ eigenvalues (where $n=3$ for this case). I am hoping there is a simple way to directly map a matrix to a qubit operator. My vague understanding is I need to write the matrix as a sum of weighted Pauli operators but I would expect there would exist some predefined function for doing this? (I have looked at the source code for the `FermionicOperator` class but it did not help me much).

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import h5py

from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import VQE, NumPyEigensolver
from qiskit.chemistry import FermionicOperator
from qiskit import Aer

backend = Aer.get_backend("qasm_simulator")

c1=1
c2=2
c3=3

ff=np.zeros((3,3))
ff[1,1]=2
ff[2,2]=1

n=3

Hamil=np.zeros((n,n))
Hamil[1,1]=c2
Hamil[2,2]=-c3/2+c2
Hamil[0,2]=np.sqrt(2)*c1
Hamil[1,2]=np.sqrt(2)*c1
Hamil[2,0]=np.sqrt(2)*c1
Hamil[2,1]=np.sqrt(2)*c1

vals,vecs=np.linalg.eig(Hamil)

print("Standard Eigenvalues: ")
print(vals)

Hamil_op = FermionicOperator(h1=Hamil)
Hamil_ops = Hamil_op.mapping(map_type='parity', threshold=1e-12)
result = NumPyEigensolver(Hamil_ops,k=int(2**n)).run()

print("Quibit Eigenvalues=")
print(result['eigenvalues'])

vqe = VQE(operator=Hamil_ops)
vqe_result = np.real(vqe.run(backend)['eigenvalue'])
print("VQE Eigenvalue")
print(vqe_result)
```

With result:

```
Standard Eigenvalues:
[-1.45426242  0.90078898  3.05347344]
Quibit Eigenvalues=
[-1.45426242+0.j -0.55347344+0.j  0.        +0.j  0.90078898+0.j
  1.59921102+0.j  2.5       +0.j  3.05347344+0.j  3.95426242+0.j]
VQE Eigenvalue
0.18608074335373637
```

Comment: Welcome to the community!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to decompose your $3 \times 3$ Hamiltonian into Pauli strings? If this is the case then it is not possible as product of Pauli matrices are in dimension of $2^n$.

Comment: Thank you for making this point clear. Still, the question stands: is it possible to represent a 3x3 matrix as a qubit operator in qiskit for use in the VQE?

Comment: Hello, I understand you want to create an Operator from a matrix, did you try the Operator class in qiskit.quantum_info? Here is the tutorial from Qiskit, does this help? https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits_advanced/02_operators_overview.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Lena, I tried looking through that documentation but it does not seem to be compatible with the ```NumPyEigensolver``` class (at least not in a straighforward way that I can figure out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe to have answered my own question through further attempts. Per the comment from KAJ226, it is true that a $(3 \times 3)$ matrix cannot be represented as a string of Paulis so I have nested the $(3 \times 3)$ matrix into a $(4 \times 4)$ matrix where the final row and column are all zeros. From this I can omit the useless eigenvalue/eigenvector and just retain the relevant results for the $(3 \times 3)$ matrix.

My solution mostly came from using the `WeightedPauliOperator`, `MatrixOperator`, and `op_converter` classes. Below is a sample of my code with corresponding outputs. Thanks to those who gave suggestions to help me out!

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import h5py

from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import VQE, NumPyEigensolver
from qiskit.aqua.operators import WeightedPauliOperator, MatrixOperator, op_converter
from qiskit import Aer

backend = Aer.get_backend("qasm_simulator")

c1=-0.5
c2=.75
c3=2

n1=3
Hamil=np.zeros((n1,n1))
Hamil[1,1]=c2
Hamil[2,2]=-c3/2+c2
Hamil[0,2]=c1
Hamil[1,2]=c1
Hamil[2,0]=c1
Hamil[2,1]=c1

print("(3x3) Hamiltonian")
print(Hamil)

vals,vecs=np.linalg.eig(Hamil)

print("Standard Eigenvalues: ")
print(vals)

n2=4
Hamil=np.zeros((n2,n2))
Hamil[1,1]=c2
Hamil[2,2]=-c3/2+c2
Hamil[0,2]=c1
Hamil[1,2]=c1
Hamil[2,0]=c1
Hamil[2,1]=c1

print("(4x4) Hamiltonian")
print(Hamil)

Hamil_Mat=MatrixOperator(Hamil)
Hamil_Qop = op_converter.to_weighted_pauli_operator(Hamil_Mat)

q_vals = NumPyEigensolver(Hamil_Qop,k=4).run()

print("Qubit Op Eigenvalues: ")
print(q_vals['eigenvalues'])

vqe=VQE(Hamil_Qop)
vqe_result=vqe.run(backend)

print("VQE Eigenvalue: ")
print(vqe_result['eigenvalue'])
```

With result:

```
(3x3) Hamiltonian
[[ 0.    0.   -0.5 ]
 [ 0.    0.75 -0.5 ]
 [-0.5  -0.5  -0.25]]
Standard Eigenvalues:
[-0.75  0.25  1.  ]
(4x4) Hamiltonian
[[ 0.    0.   -0.5   0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.75 -0.5   0.  ]
 [-0.5  -0.5  -0.25  0.  ]
 [ 0.    0.    0.    0.  ]]
Qubit Op Eigenvalues:
[-0.75+0.j  0.  +0.j  0.25+0.j  1.  +0.j]
VQE Eigenvalue:
(-0.705078125+0j)
```